# Having trouble with delete trigger on sqlite FTS5 table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm having trouble getting the delete trigger to work correctly with my sqlite FTS5 table. The database consists of ~100 tables. Each table holds the information and details for a different category of product. All product tables have two columns which are the same:
Manufacturer_Part_Number
Vendor_Part_Number

To make the entire database searchable by either part#, a FTS table is created, which has columns for these two part numbers, as well as the row_id and source table from which the record came. That way the FTS table can be queried with a part#, and the result gives the row_id and source table where the record can be located. I have triggers setup to update the FTS table when records are inserted or deleted from the actual data tables. Inserts work great, and searching and retrieving records are working great. The trouble is with deleting records.

If I try to delete a record from one of the data tables, the trigger is activated for the FTS table, and an error reports:
'**sqlite3.OperationalError: 5 values for 4 columns**'

I don't know what the problem is with my delete trigger. Its as if the 'delete' keyword is being interpreted as a value. This is being used in a python setting, using sqlite3 plugin

Here is the code for one data table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE Jacks( 
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
Manufacturer_Part_Number text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Manufacturer text,
Description text, 
Vendor_Part_Number text,
Series text,
Part_Status text,
Type text,
Gender text,
Plug_Mating_Plug_Diameter text,
Mounting_Type text,
Termination text,
Insulation text,
Features text,
Color text,
"Datasheet URL" text,
category text, 
subcategory text);
```

Here is the FTS table creation:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE searchTable USING FTS5(
manufacturer_part_number, 
vendor_part_number, 
src_row,
src_table);
```

Here are the FTS triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Jacks_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON Jacks
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO searchTable (src_row, manufacturer_part_number, vendor_part_number, src_table)
    VALUES (new.id, new.{manufacturer_part_number}, new.{vendor_part_number}, "Jacks");
END;

CREATE TRIGGER Jacks_after_delete AFTER DELETE ON Jacks
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO searchTable (src_row, manufacturer_part_number, vendor_part_number, src_table)
        VALUES ('delete', old.id, old.manufacturer_part_number, old.vendor_part_number, "Jacks");
    END;

CREATE TRIGGER Jacks_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON Jacks
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO searchTable (src_row, manufacturer_part_number, vendor_part_number, src_table)
        VALUES ('delete', old.id, old.manufacturer_part_number, old.vendor_part_number, "Jacks");
        INSERT INTO {search_table} (src_row, manufacturer_part_number, vendor_part_number, src_table)
        VALUES (new.id, new.{manufacturer_part_number}, new.{vendor_part_number}, "Jacks");
    END;
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. I'm not sure why the previous delete trigger wasnt working, but this delete trigger works. It takes a different form:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Jacks_after_delete AFTER DELETE ON Jacks
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM searchTable WHERE (old.id = src_row);
END;
```